# cron: bash syntax not working

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am trying to add following command to crontab:

```
I=1; for X in $(/bin/ls -r /var/tmp/*); do [ $((I++)) -le 28 ] && echo "lower" || echo "higher"; done
```

When executed on the command line (in bash), the command works fine. But when I add the line into crontab and when executed, cron complains:

```
/bin/sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "I++"
```

Do I need to use different syntax in cron ?

**EDIT1:**
I have replaced `sh` with `bash` in my `/etc/crontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

I have restarted `cron`, but following cron line still does not execute:

```
(I=1; for X in $(/bin/ls -r /var/tmp/*); do [ $((I++)) -le 28 ] && echo "lower" || echo "higher"; done)
```

the error suggests, that it is still being interpreted with `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "I++"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron, if I'm not mistaken, defaults to `/bin/sh`. Check `/etc/crontab/` for the line `SHELL=`. It is likely set to `/bin/sh` (`dash`). I believe you can set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your own user crontab file (the one edited by `crontab -e`). Or you can script it.

Comment: I have `SHELL=/bin/sh` in my `/etc/crontab`. Is there any reason, why I should want to use `/bin/sh`, instead of `/bin/bash` ? I am on Debian, and the system shell is `bash`. So why would they keep `sh` for cron. AFAIK, `bash` is compatible with `sh`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Nope, there is no reason to keep it set to `/bin/sh` AFAIK. I think it is just a default setting.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use `sh` syntax. You can find the specification for the portable standard `sh` syntax [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html).

In this case, you want `[ "$((i+=1))" -le 29 ]`, or if your `sh` is based on an older version of `ash` that did not support the full set of standard arithmetic operators yet, use `[ "$i" -le 28 ] ...; i=$(($i + 1))`.

A note of warning: processing a world writeable directory like `/var/tmp` under cron is like opening a can of worm wrt security.

You've got to treat filenames and their type in there as untrusted and extremely dirty.

Your `$(/bin/ls -r /var/tmp/*)` in particular is bogus as it makes a lot of assumptions on what characters the filenames may contain and assumes none of them are directories or symlinks to directories.

Comment: when I use `[ "$((I+=1))" -le 28 ]`, cron complains: `/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution`

Answer (score 2):

To make this completely portable you can replace the $() syntax with:

```
I=1; for X in `/bin/ls -r /var/tmp/*`; do [ $I -le 28 ] && echo "lower" || echo "higher"; I=`expr $I + 1`; done
```

But beware of cron jobs and world writable directories.